# Exportar variables del script de servidor de Node JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy intentando **exportar** una **variable** de mi **script** *(Server.js)* hacia otro script *(articleHandler.js)* usando la siguiente linea de **código** en el script del **servidor**

```
module.exports = myVariable;
```

Lo cual no me ha dado éxito alguno, ya que al ejecutar el **script** *articleHandler.js* me devuelve el siguiente **error**

> Creating routers...
>
> Routers created.
>
> Running @ localhost:3000
>
> [Function: queryExport]
>
> events.js:183
>
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> ^
>
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
>
> at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
>
> at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
>
> at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1355:14)
>
> at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
>
> at Server.listen (net.js:1480:7)
>
> at Function.listen
>
> (/Users/default/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
>
> at Object. (/Users/default/project/DemoPage/server.js:46:5)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:565:32)

Este es mi **script** *Server.js*

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
var queryResponse;

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'www')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

console.log("Creating routers...");
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});


app.get('/new-article', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/www/admin-dashboard/new- 
article.html'));
});
console.log("Routers created.");


app.post("/new-article", function (req, res) {
queryResponse = req.body.articleName;
console.log("New article: " + queryResponse);

res.send({
query: queryResponse
});
});

//Esto no funciona
var queryExport = function(){
return queryResponse;
}
module.exports = queryExport;

//Esto tampoco
//module.exports.queryResponse = queryResponse;

app.listen(port);
console.log("Running @ localhost:3000");
```

Y este es mi script *articleHandler.js* en el cual quiero **importar** la variable ***queryResponse*** desde **Server.js**

```
let queryResponse = require("./server.js");
console.log(queryResponse);
```

Alguna idea de a qué se deba este error?

Comment: El error `EADDRINUSE` quiere decir que el puerto ya está usado, y no tiene **absolutamente nada** que ver con lo que estás preguntando sobre *exportar* variables. ¿ Podrías aclarar un poco tu pregunta ?

Comment: Lo que necesito es hacer que la variable queryResponse de server.js pueda leerla desde articleHandler.js.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y quita todo el *ruido* del error que indicas, que no viene al caso. Con una pregunta clara, es posible que obtengas mas y mejores respuestas :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casi lo tienes. Solo te falta una cosa: puesto que estás *exportando* una función, tienes que **llamarla**:

```
let queryResponse = ( require("./server.js") )( );

console.log(queryResponse);
```

También podrías hacer, en tu `server.js`:

```
var queryResponse;
...
module.exports = queryResponse;
```

Con lo que podrías *importarla* así:

```
let externalQueryResponse = require( './server.js' );
```

O incluso podrias, en tu `server.js`:

```
var queryResponse;
...
module.exports = {
  queryResponse: queryResponse
}
```

Y luego la *importas* así:

```
const ServerJs = require( './server.js' );

console.log( ServerJs.queryResponse );
```

También podrías usar `import`, pero ya nos estamos extendiendo demasiado :-)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Esto era exactamente lo que estaba necesitando.

Comment: jejejej tienes razón @Trauma disculpa lo apresurado